# Binary search in C using recursive function with return type

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree, infinite-loop

Here below, I am trying to write a simple binary search program using recursive function. When I run it, It takes the array and key to be searched as input but after that the compiler stops abruptly. Maybe because of an infinite loop somewhere.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int present_flag;
int binary_search(int array[],int low,int high,int key)
{
int mid=(high + low)/2;
if(low<=high)
{
    if (array[mid] == key)
    {
    printf("Key found at index %d \n",mid);
    return 1;
    }
        else if (array[mid] >key)
        return 0+binary_search(array,low,mid,key);
            else 
            return 0+binary_search(array,mid+1,high,key);;
}
else return 0;
}
main()
{
int array[9],i,n,key;
printf("Enter 9 numbers in asc order \n");
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter number to be searched\n");
scanf("%d",&key);
present_flag=binary_search(array,0,8,key);
if (present_flag==0 )
printf("Number not present in array\n");
}
```

Comment: how comes it starts  to run and then the compiler stops? are you mixed up with the dibugger?

Comment: Just wondering: do you realize that your array isn't filled, ever, as you just store the input in n 9 times over?  And please do yourself (and us) a favor: indent your code properly.

Comment: why are you adding zero plus `binary_search()` return value?

Answer (score 1):

Fill the `array` first

Fix :

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++) //Assuming your n is 9
  scanf("%d",&array[i]);
              ^^^ not n
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class BinarySearch
{
// Returns index of x if it is present in arr[], else
// return -1
int binarySearch(int arr[], int x)
{
    int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1;
    while (l <= r)
    {
        int m = l + (r-l)/2;

        // Check if x is present at mid
        if (arr[m] == x)
            return m;

        // If x greater, ignore left half
        if (arr[m] < x)
            l = m + 1;

        // If x is smaller, ignore right half
        else
            r = m - 1;
    }

    // if we reach here, then element was not present
    return -1;
}
```

For More Info,
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Answer (score 0):

First thing its not the `compiler` that got stopped. The compiler only converts your program into machine level instructions.

Secondly, the recursive calls wont stop. Because you didn't exactly specify the terminating conditions. Hence, your program was `executing` indefinitely until it runs out of stack space ending up with a `segmentation fault`.

The corrected code looks as follows (I specified the changes in the comments program):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int present_flag;
int binary_search(int array[],int low,int high,int key)
{

if(low==high)//if boundaries are same, just compare with the value and return
             //appropriately...
{
    if(array[low]==key){
    printf("Key found at index %d \n",low);
    return 1;
}
else
return 0;
}
int mid=(high + low)/2;
if(low<high)
{
    if (array[mid] == key)
    {
    printf("Key found at index %d \n",mid);
    return 1;
    }
        else if (array[mid] >key)
        return binary_search(array,low,mid,key);//need not put a zero explicitly...
            else 
            return binary_search(array,mid+1,high,key);
}
else return 0;
}
main()
{
int array[9],i,n,key;
printf("Enter 9 numbers in asc order \n");
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
scanf("%d",&array[i]);// <--- this should be array[i] and not n. 
printf("Enter number to be searched\n");
scanf("%d",&key);
present_flag=binary_search(array,0,8,key);
if (present_flag==0 )
printf("Number not present in array\n");
}
```

Re-writing the function in a more simplified way we get:

```
int binary_search(int array[],int low,int high,int key)
{
    int mid=(high + low)/2;
    if (array[mid] == key)
    {
        printf("Key found at index %d \n",mid);
        return 1;
    }
    if(low<high)
    {
        if(array[mid] >key)
          return binary_search(array,low,mid,key);
        else 
          return binary_search(array,mid+1,high,key);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you dont need to write whole program just tell implementation.that better

Answer (score 0):

In response to nitish712's simplified version of the code, another way we could further simplify the code would be to simply return -1 (instead of 0 for the case where the element is not present), and return mid itself when the element is present :

```
int binary_search(int array[],int low,int high,int key)
{
int mid=(high + low)/2;
if (array[mid] == key)
{

    return mid;//This value can be utilized elsewhere in the code to check availability of the key in the array
}
if(low<high)
{
    if(array[mid] >key)
      return binary_search(array,low,mid,key);
    else 
      return binary_search(array,mid+1,high,key);
}
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet below is a simple implementation of binary search,

```
bool search_recursive(int value, int values[], int lower, int upper) 
{
    if (lower > upper) return -1;
    int mid = (lower + upper) / 2;

    if (value == values[mid]) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (value > values[mid]) {
        // Search right half
        return search_recursive(value, values, mid + 1, upper);
    } else {
        // Search left half
        return search_recursive(value, values, lower, upper - 1);
    }
}
```